# How to show UIProgressView with MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mkmapview, uiprogressview

In my application, i have latitude and longitude values to show a location in MKMapView. In previous version i have used UIActivityIndicator until Mapscreen loads in MKMapView. Now i want to show a UIProgressView instead of UIActivityIndicator.

Is it possible to show a progress with MKMapView? I searched lot and couldn't get proper or related solution so for.

Note:
What i have used with UIProgressView is uploading and downloading files with NSURLConnection. I want to know the process time of map loading section, then only i will able to show progress ? right.

Any one plz help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `MKMapView` doesn't natively support this.

You can check [MKMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) and there are no such delegate methods. All you can get from it is only when map starts and finishes loading the data.